# Using layouts, partials, and includeContent() in CFWheels

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm stumped trying to get static content, partials, and layouts to behave and display. I am trying to create:

- 1 main layout to hold header/footer data
- 1 partial view for the homepage since it's body layout is different
- 1 partial view for all other pages

All partials should feed into the main layout which I will build under views/layout.cfm

Here are the files.

**Controller/Home.cfc** - contains functions for index and privacy

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller">

    <cffunction name="index">

        <cfset qRecipes = model("tblRecipes").findAll(
            select="id, name, image, homepage_order",
            where="homepage_order > 0",
            order="homepage_order",
            maxrows=4
        ) />
     </cffunction>

     <cffunction name="privacy">

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

**views/home/index.cfm** - Should display the homepage layout
**views/home/privacy.cfm** - Contain static text wrapped in `cfsavecontent` like so.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
xxxxxxxx
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset contentFor("foo") />
```

The documentation doesn't provide enough in-depth examples for me grasp at what I'm missing. The main layout will look like:

```
<cfoutput>#includePartial("/shared/header")#
#styleSheetLinkTag(source="homepage", head=true)#
</cfoutput>asdfsafd

    <body>

        <div id="page-wrap">

        <header>
            <cfoutput>#includePartial(partial="/shared/socialmedia", cache=1440)#</cfoutput>

            <nav id="top-navigation">
                <cfoutput>#includePartial("/shared/topnav")#</cfoutput>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <cfoutput>#includeContent()#</cfoutput> <!--- All partial data should output here --->
    </body>
</html>
```

Since I'm placing all the text for privacy into a variable would I need another page to output `#includeContent("foo")#` before the main layout would load? Or can I have a page full of text not have to be wrapped in `cfsavecontent`?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing your own framework. Is there a reason why you decided not to use a community supported one liek FW/1 or Coldbox? Both of these support this kind of 'nesting' out of the box.

Comment: @ScottStroz they tagged it `cfwheels` so they are using a community framework.

Comment: Missed that....my bad...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to wrap your Privacy page in `<cfsavecontent>`. Try it without the `<cfsavecontent>` tags and without the `contentFor("foo")`. Then its contents should appear where you have `#includeContent()#` in the main layout.

What are you trying to do with the home page that's different? Anything?